# Postgres EXPLAIN ANALYZE cost estimate row count massively higher than actual row count. No Vacuuming?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I have a Postgres 9.4.18 database running on Heroku in a Django project.  I had noticed that queries were becoming increasingly slow so I ran an "EXPLAIN ANALYZE" on one query and noticed that for one node the row estimate was massively higher than the actual row count:

```
->  Seq Scan on listings_listing u1  (cost=0.00..1536692.01 rows=5030003 width=8) (actual time=0.811..11263.410 rows=173537 loops=1)
```

I then ran "VACUUM FULL ANALYZE" on the table and then reran the "EXPLAIN ANALYZE" on the query and got:

```
->  Seq Scan on listings_listing u1  (cost=0.00..23554.61 rows=173537 width=8) (actual time=0.001..33.884 rows=173537 loops=1)
```

The execution time is now 100x faster.

So the two questions are: A) shouldn't auto vacuuming be preventing this? (how do I check if that is enabled?) B) how did it get this way assuming the vacuuming isn't being performed?

---------------------------------  Update

I found this command from heroku that gives autovacuum stats and here is the output (unfortunately I ran it after my manual vacuum.

```
heroku pg:vacuum_stats DATABASE_URL

schema |                  table                  | last_vacuum | last_autovacuum  |    rowcount    | dead_rowcount  | autovacuum_threshold | expect_autovacuum 
--------+-----------------------------------------+-------------+------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------------+-------------------
 public | listings_listing                        |             | 2018-06-27 15:36 |        173,537 |              0 |         34,757       |
```

It would seem the threshold indicated should have caused it to run vacuum a long time ago.

Also, here is the Heroku page for their documentation on vacuuming settings:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/managing-vacuum-on-heroku-postgres

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find out if autovacuum is enabled as it should be, run

```
SHOW autovacuum;
```

To find out if autovacuum is disabled for your specific table, run

```
SELECT reloptions FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'listings_listing';
```

The answer to B) is simple:

If autovacuum isn't running, every `UPDATE` or `DELETE` will create a “dead tuple” (or “dead row version”) in the table. These will never be cleaned up unless you run `VACUUM` manually and will cause the table to grow so that sequential scans become slower.

The answer to A) is more difficult:

There are several things that can keep autovacuum from doing its job:

- The rate of changes to this table can be so high that autovacuum, which runs slow be default so that it does not disturb normal activity, cannot keep up.

  In this case you should tune autovacuum to be more aggressive for this table:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE listings_listing SET (
     autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit = 1000,
     toast.autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit = 1000
  );
  ```

  If that is not good enough, you can

  ```
  ALTER TABLE listings_listing SET (
     autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 0,
     toast.autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 0
  );
  ```
- There are concurrent long transactions.

  Autovacuum can only remove dead tuples that are older than the oldest running transaction, so long transactions can keep it from doing its job.

  There is more to the story; read [this blog post](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/reasons-why-vacuum-wont-remove-dead-rows/).

  However, this would also keep `VACUUM (FULL)` from doing its job, so maybe that is not your problem.
- The table is frequently locked with `SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE` or stronger locks, for example by running “`LOCK listings_listing`”.

  When autovacuum encounters such a lock, it backs down rather than blocking user activity.

A useful way to determine what is going on is to query `pg_stat_user_tables` like this:

```
SELECT n_live_tup, n_dead_tup, last_vacuum, last_autovacuum
FROM pg_stat_user_tables
WHERE relname = 'listings_listing';
```

But that evidence is probably destroyed now that you have run `VACUUM (FULL)`.

Another good thing to do is to set `log_autovacuum_min_duration` to something else than -1 and look into the log occasionally.

Comment: Thanks.  Running your commands shows autovacuum is on and not disabled for this table.  pg_stat_user_tables shows the last_autovacuum was done 2018-06-27.  I also ran a heroku command that shows the autovacuum_threshold is 34,757 rows.  So I don't see why it hadn't run yet.  Or is that different than autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay?  I don't perform long locks on this table.

Comment: Perhaps there was just a bulk delete. Monitor the table bloat and see what happens.

Comment: I run a task to delete stale listings every 15 mins so a bulk delete would be unlikely.  I'm going to try monitoring bloat.  Is the idea with changing the cost_delay that possibly it is trying to vacuum but it keeps going to sleep?  My service is not that popular so I would find that hard to believe.

Comment: Autovacuum goes slow by default, it takes a break ever so often. Don't tune it unless you know it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Laurenz Albe's answer is excellent for explaining what was up with auto vacuuming but I wanted to now answer what I later found out about why my dead tuples count was ballooning.

Basically due to a bug in my code I was updating every row in the database every 15 mins instead of just the ones matching a filter.  Each update created a dead tuple and it was bloating so fast that the vacuuming couldn't keep up.  It took me a while to find the bug because I was only looking at the deletes in the code and not the updates as I didn't realize (at the time) that they too create dead tuples.

After fixing that there was no need to change any of the auto vacuuming settings.  The bloat increase was normal.